# Dynamically show and hide JFrame decorations

Tags: java, swing, window-decoration

I am developing a Java Swing-based application with different perspectives. For the "main menu" perspective I do not want the window (JFrame) to be decorated, while in other perspective I do want the window to be decorated. In other words, I need want to change the decoration attribute dynamically.

I have tried to use `setUndecorated(false)` and `setUndecorated(true)`, but I seems I can only set this once, before actually showing the window.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the javadoc:

> Disables or enables decorations for this frame. This method can only be called while the frame is not displayable.

Therefore, once the `JFrame` is packed and/or displayed, you can no longer change that value. If you want to change the `undecorated` state of a `JFrame` you will need to `dispose()` it first, then change the state and eventually make it visible again.

Comment: It worked as you described, thank you ! The procedure is described in the documentation of `Window.dispose()', but I didn't know where to look for that

Answer (score 0):

After all, I had to take a different approach.
The former solution did work, as I stated in my last comment.
However, it was showing the default LAF window decoration, while I was using a different LAF.
So the result was graphically inconsistent with the rest of the LAF. Finally, I came with the right solution, I used setUndecorate(true) for my frame. Then, when I had to change my perspective to one using decorations I simply had to use the following code

```
contentPane.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
```

And when I had to revert to the non decorate perspective, I use

```
contentPane.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
```

This approach didn't need to dispose the window and show it again (which actually produced a brief but still visible hide/show of the window)

Comment: Which LAF did this work with? It does not seem to work with the OS X aqua LAF (Java8/OS X 10.9.5).